# How do route traffic Hyper-V From Linux to Windows

Tags: networking, linux-networking, hyper-v, dhcp, gateway

I have a Windows Server With Hyper-V
We have Linux VM on this Hyper-V which Have inside DHCP Server

What I want to do is route traffic from [Linux]-[Gateway] To VMS Which have IPS from DHCP Server

Why ?

We all knows Linux is better at networking than Windows so i can create a better Firewall in Linux
So all packets which came from Linux Server [Gateway] is filtered and gone through firewall

I hope also you give me examples with public IPs not private

Switch Connection is Internal

Screen Shots

[Linux DHCP Server Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPeIk.png)

[VM Can Take IP from DHCP Server With MAC Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLwjP.png)